# Checking the CheckBoxPrefrence through Program

Tags: android, android-preferences

We know that we can set a normal `CheckBox` by using the `setChecked(boolean)` method.
Is it possible to set the `CheckBoxPreference` through a method ?
Does there exist any method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about... [`setChecked(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/TwoStatePreference.html#setChecked%28boolean%29)? When you get a reference to your `CheckBoxPreference` (e.g. in your `PreferenceActivity` or `PreferenceFragment`) you should have no problem using this method.

---

I'm not sure what part you're having trouble with, but the method call to `CheckBoxPreference`'s `setChecked(boolean)` is no different from that of a regular `CheckBox` (as in: you just pass along a boolean value representing the 'tick'):

```
CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
// or:
CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("checkbox_pref");
checkboxPref.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: can you please explain the same thing with an example

Comment: @ArunKumarSharma: I added a basic example showing its usage. Is there anything in particular you're having any issues with?